# How can i select all except specific ids using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to select all ids except specific which like `28, 29, 30, 40`. I tried following query.

```
SELECT * FROM oc_product_to_category WHERE product_id !IN  (28, 29, 30, 40)
```

I searched about it and find [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in). but it `expr IN  (28, 29, 30, 40)` does not working. Can any is this possible with sql function?  I would like to appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `NOT IN`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM oc_product_to_category 
WHERE product_id  NOT IN  (28, 29, 30, 40)
```